# Report Builder #Error on sum of dataset

Tags: vb.net, reporting, reportbuilder

In my report, I have columns where I sum row values.

The following column values sum successfully

```
=Sum(Fields!alphas.Value)

=Sum(Fields!betas.Value)
```

However, when I try to sum a column of alphas/betas, I am receiving an #Error printing on the report.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!betas.Value>0,Fields!alphas.Value/Fields!betas.Value,0))
```

I have tried adding checks inside the `IIF` to check if alphas `IsNumeric` and betas IsNumeric.  I have also tried inside the `IIF` to check if alphas is Not `IsNothing` and betas is Not IsNothing.

What could be causing #Error to be printed on the report?

Answer (score 2):

You have checked for everything else but not for when betas.value = 0
IIF frequently catches people out because it doesn't short-circuit; both parts are always evaluated, so you will get a division by zero when betas.value = 0